# How import an utility method in a client script

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose to have two principle folders:
lib (folder) and in this folder there is a utils.js file
static (folder) with a element.js file

In the utils.js file the code is:

```
'use strict';

var Utils = {};

Utils.getPrint = function() {
    return "hello";
};

module.exports = Utils;
```

Now in the static folder the element.js file is a client script so:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
// I must import utils.js file but I don't know how do this. Something like 
var utils=require();
    $(document).ready(function() {


        });


}());
```

Anyone can help me how code I must write to import utils.js file in element.js file?

Answer (score 1):

If the files are in the same directory, `require` the name of the file (without `.js`):

```
// element.js
var utils = require('utils');

(function () {

    utils.getPrint();

})();
```

If the files are not in the same directory, use relative paths to reference the file you want to import:

```
// element.js
// folder/
//    utils.js

var utils = require('./folder/utils');

// utils.js
// folder/
//    element.js

var utils = require('../utils');
```

Comment: I put utils.js in the same folder of element.js and I use your first suggestion and I obtain module name has not been loaded yet for context _. use require( )

Comment: [Searching stackoverflow for that error message](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=module+name+has+not+been+loaded) seems to return useful results.